# Append custom sitemap to sitemap index

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I have a custom generated sitemap which I'd like to append to my SEOmatic sitemap.xml file.

Is this possible?

I suppose the simple alternative would be to just add an extra sitemap to Google Search Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been added in SEOmatic 3.1.36 as per [this release announcement tweet](https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1072260946276597767)

You can do it via the GUI in **SEOmatic** -> **Site Settings** -> **Sitemap**: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#additional-sitemaps

[image: Additional Sitemaps]

...or you can do it via plugin:

```
use nystudio107\seomatic\events\RegisterSitemapsEvent;
use nystudio107\seomatic\models\SitemapIndexTemplate;
use yii\base\Event;
Event::on(SitemapIndexTemplate::class, SitemapIndexTemplate::EVENT_REGISTER_SITEMAPS, function(RegisterSitemapsEvent $e) {
    $e->sitemaps[] = [
        'loc' => $url,
        'lastmod' => $lastMod,
    ];
});
```

Comment: No worries! Let me know how you go.

Comment: Your update works great. If I had to change anything I'd like to be able to include a {{SiteUrl}} variable (or similar) in the sitemap path.

Comment: File a FR for it! https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/issues -- should be easy to do

Comment: Also mark this as the accepted answer if you're satisfied with it, so SE can stay happy :)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty simple...

If you navigate to **SEOmatic → Site Settings → Miscellaneous**, you'll see a table at the bottom of the page where you can input custom sitemap urls.

[image: SEOmatic Miscellaneous Site Settings]

Once you add a url in here and save it, it will get added to a custom index sitemap that is included at the bottom of your main index sitemap:

**/sitemaps/1/sitemap.xml**

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  ...
  <sitemap>
    <loc> http://site.test/sitemaps/1/global/custom/1/sitemap.xml </loc>
    <lastmod> 2018-11-16T10:06:31-05:00 </lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

**/sitemaps/1/global/custom/1/sitemap.xml**

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc> http://site.test/custom.xml </loc>
    <lastmod> 2018-12-07T14:26:25-05:00 </lastmod>
    <changefreq> weekly </changefreq>
    <priority> 0.5 </priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

for more info → https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#additional-sitemap-urls

Comment: You can also do it programmatically via PHP as well. Same link that Jalen mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Jalen - I did see this function but it looks like it only supports adding individual URLs - not other sitemaps. Ideally I want to add a new sitemap to the sitemapindex. I'm not sure whether Google will parse a sitemap.xml which is supplied as an individual URL rather than as part of a sitemapindex. Perhaps a feature request is in order :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood everything here... it looks like what you want is the ability to add additional sitemaps generated externally, and what SEOmatic lets you do is add URLs to _one_ additional `custom` sitemap. Yep, file a FR for this one @WaydeChristie